# Getting CellDingbat to remember its state between Mathematica sessions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, stylesheet

I have modified my notebook's stylesheet to include a `StyleData["Todo"]` that inherits from `StyleData["Item"]`. It changes the cell dingbat to a checkbox. In the stylesheet editor:

```
Cell[StyleData["ToDo", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Item"]], 
  CellDingbat->DynamicModuleBox[{$CellContext`color$$}, 
    CheckboxBox[
    Dynamic[$CellContext`color$$], {RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0],RGBColor[0,Rational[2, 3], 0]},    
    Background -> Dynamic[$CellContext`color$$]], 
    DynamicModuleValues :> {}
  ],
]
```

The problem is that the state of the checkbox, when used in a notebook, is not saved between Mathematica sessions. I thought the `DynamicModule[]` would do the trick. How do I get the checkbox to remember its state?

**EDIT**

Simon's solution does save the state of the checkbox, but the checkbox is clipped when used as a CellDingbat (MacOS X). Putting Simon's code in a CellFrameLabels options does the trick, and also keeps the default "Item" CellDingbat. Here is what I've gone with:

```
Cell[StyleData["ToDo", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Item"]],
 CellFrameLabels->{{
    ButtonBox[
     CheckboxBox[False], ButtonFunction :> (SelectionMove[
        ButtonNotebook[], All, ButtonCell]; 
      With[{$CellContext`new = ReplaceAll[
           Options[
            NotebookSelection[
             ButtonNotebook[]], CellFrameLabels], CheckboxBox[
             Pattern[$CellContext`x, 
              Alternatives[True, False]]] :> CheckboxBox[
             Not[$CellContext`x]]]}, 
        SetOptions[
         NotebookSelection[
          ButtonNotebook[]], $CellContext`new]]; SelectionMove[
        ButtonNotebook[], After, CellContents]), Appearance -> None, 
     Method -> "Preemptive", Evaluator -> Automatic], None}, {
   None, None}},
 MenuSortingValue->1621]
```

Comment: Difficult. BTW you can replace ``$CellContext`color$$`` by just `colors` if you set the `Cell` option `CellContext->Cell`

Comment: When I pasted the code above I got the Message "An improperly formatted directive with head Symbol was encountered."  Is that expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code (I think) is that a new `DynamicModule` does not get created each time you create a new "ToDo" cell. So there is nowhere that the state of each `Checkbox` can get saved.

The simplest solution I could think of for storing the state of the `Checkbox` for each "ToDo" cell is to overwrite the `CellDingbat` the first time that the `Checkbox` is activated. 
(Other options I played with were using `TaggingRules`, 
toggling between "ToDo" and "ToDone" styles, etc...)

However, even a plain `Checkbox` in a `CellDingbat` does not store its state - try running the following then cycle the output through a [Show Expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/ShowExpression.html) cycle.

```
CellPrint[Cell["test", "Text", CellDingbat -> ToBoxes[Checkbox[]]]]
```

To get around this, I used `Checkbox` with the definite argument `True` or `False` wrapped up in a button that changes the state. This is stupid and inefficient, but it works!

So, my code for the cell style

```
Cell[StyleData["ToDo", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Item"]],
 CellDingbat -> ButtonBox[CheckboxBox[False], 
   ButtonFunction :> (SelectionMove[ButtonNotebook[], All, ButtonCell]; 
     With[{$CellContext`new = ReplaceAll[
          Options[NotebookSelection[ButtonNotebook[]], CellDingbat], 
          CheckboxBox[Pattern[$CellContext`x, Alternatives[True, False]]] :> CheckboxBox[Not[$CellContext`x]]]}, 
        SetOptions[NotebookSelection[ButtonNotebook[]], $CellContext`new]]; 
      SelectionMove[ButtonNotebook[], After, CellContents]), 
    Appearance -> None, Method -> "Preemptive", Evaluator -> Automatic]]
```

[image: Screenshota]

I'm not happy with this solution, but it's the best I've come up with. An improvement would be to move the button function code out of the cell so that it is not repeated for every checked ToDo cell. Also to make it run without a `ReplaceAll` so that the kernel is not needed and the function can be run using just the frontend.

Comment: This is close. The checkbox button is clipped at the top, and so is the checkmark. I've tried numerous padding, margin and size options to both the button, the cell, the checkbox, to no avail.

Comment: @JxB: It looks fine for me - but different operating systems display these things differently. I've posted a screen shot of it on my system (Ubuntu 11.10, Mathematica 8.01)