# Temporarily disabling all input cells in a section of a notebook

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

Is there a way to disable all input cells in a cell group / section, in a way that is easily reversed later?

My aim is to keep a section of a notebook intact, but prevent it from being evaluated when "Evaluate Notebook" is selected in the front end.

There's Cell -> Cell properties -> Evaluatable, but using this would require me to select every input cell manually and change/restore this property.  This is too much work.  I have text/subsection/output cells interlaced.

Is there a better way using the UI?  If not, is there a *simple* programmatic way?

**EDIT:** I found Alt-click, which selects *all* input cells in the notebook.  Can this be restricted to a section / cell-group only?

Comment: This is an interesting question.  I would take it one step further, and ask: is there a way to create an `Evaluatable` toggle for each section?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard For the toggle UI part this may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7932172/695132

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Option-click to select all Input cells.
- Command-click twice (once to select, once to deselect) each cell group you don't want to include.

Also, you could just set Evaluatable->False on the entire cell group you want to disable.  The Text, Subsection, & Output cells in that group won't cause any problems.

Comment: If I set Evaluatable on a Text cell, it will indeed become evaluatable (which is undesirable), the other method works though.  I do wish there were a method which requires operation on the relevant cells only, and not everything else (i.e. here it's necessary to deselect everything else).  **Do you know where these mouse shortcuts are documented?**  I couldn't find them.

Comment: Shift-click and command-click behave the same in Mathematica as in nearly every other piece of desktop software in existence.  I wouldn't be surprised if they're not documented anywhere.  Option-click does have a unique behavior in Mathematica.  I don't know whether or not it's documented.