# How to achieve cell content dependent CellFrameLabels

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The more general questions are: How to perform kernel computations within styling options, and how to access the cell's content in one of its styling options (e.g. CellFrameLabels).

What I would like to do is base a CellFrameLabels on the content of the cell's CellTags, with the CellFrameLabels defined in a stylesheet. From [Getting CellDingbat to remember its state between Mathematica sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932172/getting-celldingbat-to-remember-its-state-between-mathematica-sessions) I saw that kernel computations can be done inside of cell styling options with the use of dynamic and controls, but how to I refer to the cell currently being formatted? Is there some sort of equivalent to EvaluationCell for the formatting action? I realize that even if there was such a thing as "FormattedCell", I probably couldn't use `SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],All,FormattedCell]`, but I hope you get the idea of what I'm trying to get. I tried to use CurrentValue, but I'm getting a $Failed.

---

I'm sorry for the lack of clarity. I'll partly answer my question here as a way to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish. However, what I would really like is stylesheet code that gives the same result in real-time as the cells are styled.

```
NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "TAG1", All, CellTags];
SetOptions[NotebookSelection[],
  CellFrameLabels->{{Cell[TextData[{"T1"}],CellBaseline->Baseline,BaseStyle->Text],
      Inherited},{Inherited, Inherited}}];
NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "TAG2", All, CellTags];
SetOptions[NotebookSelection[],
  CellFrameLabels->{{Cell[TextData[{"T2"}],CellBaseline->Baseline,BaseStyle->Text],
      Inherited},{Inherited, Inherited}}];
```

Can I, in a stylesheet, set the value of CellFrameLabels dependent on the cell's own tags, as is being done in the code above (in the code above, by iterating after-the-fact on each cell in the notebook)? Maybe it's not possible. Just asking.

Comment: This is only just barely a programming question, so it is arguably off-topic of StackOverflow. You might be better off asking on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/. But if you do, please edit your question to make it clearer and explain what you tried. I am finding it hard to work out what it is you are trying to do.